# Can I use a variable in a stage path?

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I'm using a `COPY INTO` statement to load some tables into S3:

```sql
COPY INTO 's3://sandbox-staging/US/'
FROM US
storage_integration = sandbox
FILE_FORMAT = (
  type = 'parquet'
)
header = true
overwrite = true;
```

I have to do a migration like this for every state. To save some time and protect against human error, I'd love to set the table name as a variable, so that I can use it in both the `COPY INTO` and `FROM` clauses. For example:

```sql
SET loc = 'US_NY';
SET staging_path = 's3://sandbox-staging/' || $loc || '/';
COPY INTO $staging_path
FROM table($loc)
storage_integration = sandbox
FILE_FORMAT = (
  type = 'parquet'
)
header = true
overwrite = true;
```

The `FROM` clause works, it's the `COPY INTO` I can't seem to get right. In the same sense that there's a `table` function for table literals, is there any literal function I can use for staging paths?

Comment: I haven't found a way. For stage paths specifically, the only option I've found is dynamically building the SQL through a stored procedure. I posted a general-purpose stored procedure to do this a while back... https://snowflake.pavlik.us/index.php/2021/01/22/running-dynamic-sql-in-snowflake/

Answer (score 0):

You can try using a variable with execute immediate to dynamically generate the command. https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/sql/execute-immediate.html

```
SET loc = 'US_NY';
SET staging_path =  '''s3://sandbox-staging/' || $loc || '/''' ;
SET copy_command= 
'COPY INTO ' || $staging_path ||
' FROM  '  || $loc ||
' storage_integration = sandbox
FILE_FORMAT = (
  type = \'parquet\'
)
header = true
overwrite = true;';

EXECUTE IMMEDIATE $copy_command;
```

To view the copy command code you can run:

`SELECT $copy_command;`

Output:

`COPY INTO 's3://sandbox-staging/US_NY/' FROM  US_NY storage_integration = sandbox FILE_FORMAT = ( type = 'parquet' ) header = true overwrite = true;`

Answer (score 0):

Going to the original requirement - running this for all states - this is tailor made for a SQL generator.

```
create or replace table TABLE_LIST(NAME string);

insert into TABLE_LIST (NAME) values ('US_NY'), ('US_CA'), ('US_NC'), ('US_FL');

select $$
COPY INTO 's3://sandbox-staging/$$ || NAME || $$/'$$ || $$
FROM $$ || NAME || $$
storage_integration = sandbox
FILE_FORMAT = (
  type = 'parquet'
)
header = true
overwrite = true
$$ as SQL_COMMAND
from TABLE_LIST;
```

That will generate all the SQL commands in a table. If you want to automate running them, you can use a stored procedure to do that. For running generated SQL statements, there's one available to do that already.

https://snowflake.pavlik.us/index.php/2019/08/22/executing-multiple-sql-statements-in-a-stored-procedure/

You can then call it like this:

```
call RunBatchSQL($$ 

 select 'COPY INTO ''s3://sandbox-staging/' || NAME || '\'' ||
' FROM ' || NAME ||
' storage_integration = sandbox
FILE_FORMAT = (
  type = ''parquet''
)
header = true
overwrite = true'
 as SQL_COMMAND
from TABLE_LIST;

$$);
```

It may be cleaner to write a stored procedure from scratch, but this allows you to run any generated SQL statements.